# Facebook FQL to get all status messages from an app

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am attempting to get a list of all friend messages posted by the Facebook for Android application.  The Facebook for Android application has app_id=350685531728.

This returns all friend user ids:

```
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $facebook_user_id
```

This returns all Facebook for Android postings for a user id:

```
SELECT message, app_id FROM stream WHERE app_id = 350685531728 AND source_id IN ($facebook_user_id)
```

**But this returns an empty set:**

```
SELECT message, app_id FROM stream WHERE app_id = 350685531728 AND source_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $facebook_user_id)
```

Can someone tell me how to fix my query so that it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bunch of testing on this.  As far as I can tell there's some oddness with FQL when querying some tables.  After adding a LIMIT to my status query it is returning the expected results.

Reference: http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=9639